# Brew package won't build due to a missing license

Tags: c#, linux, xamarin, mono, homebrew

I could not find anything similar to this, troubleshooting doesn't seem to have similar issues of a missing license.

How to get this license file and where to add it, as it may be the issue which fails the whole build ?

Any insight is much appreciated.

```
alex31@Air3:~$ `brew install scriptcs`

    ==> Installing dependencies for scriptcs: mono
    ==> Installing scriptcs dependency: mono
    ==> Downloading https://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-6.4.0.198.ta
    Already downloaded: /home/alex31/.cache/Homebrew/downloads/0f5bd5d4725f08bae7e853625da4da3ccdbb326dfa62820ffd3410b49ea6d64b--mono-6.4.0.198.tar.xz
    ==> ./configure --prefix=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mono/6.4.0.198 --disa
    ==> make
    ==> make install
    ==> Cloning https://github.com/mono/msbuild.git
Updating /home/alex31/.cache/Homebrew/mono--msbuild--git
=> Checking out revision ad9c9926a76e3db0d2b878a24d44446d73640d19
HEAD is now at ad9c9926 Merge pull request #109 from radical/roslyn-bump-2019-02
HEAD is now at ad9c9926 Merge pull request #109 from radical/roslyn-bump-2019-02
    ==> ./eng/cibuild_bootstrapped_msbuild.sh --host_type mono --configuration Relea

Last 15 lines from /home/alex31/.cache/Homebrew/Logs/mono/04.cibuild_bootstrapped_msbuild.sh:
/tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/.packages/microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk/1.0.0-beta.19207.1    
/tools/RepositoryValidation.proj(29,5): error : No license file found in '/tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/'.               
 Xunit.NetCore.Extensions -> /tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/artifacts    /bin/Xunit.NetCore.Extensions/Release-MONO/net472/Xunit.NetCore.Extensions.dll
  Dependency -> /tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/artifacts/bin/Samples/Dependency/Release-MONO/net472/Dependency.dll
   PortableTask -> /tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/artifacts/bin/Samples/PortableTask    /Release-MONO/netstandard1.3/PortableTask.dll
  TaskUsageLogger -> /tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/artifacts/bin/Samples/TaskUsageLogger/Release-MONO/net472/TaskUsageLogger.dll
   XmlFileLogger -> /tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/artifacts/bin/Samples/XmlFileLogger/Release-MONO/net472/XmlFileLogger.dll

Build FAILED.

/tmp/mono--msbuild-20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/.packages/microsoft.dotnet.arcade.sdk/1.0.0-beta.19207.1                   
/tools/RepositoryValidation.proj(29,5): error : No license file found in '/tmp/mono- -msbuiild20191101-2457-1g9gbaz/'.                
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:11:11.71
Build failed (exit code '1').

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been issues with Linuxbrew's mono installation, so I wouldn't get my hopes up for getting it to work anytime soon. This is what the Linuxbrew maintainer said a month ago:

> Yes, I gave up on mono a few weeks ago. Let's close this, we can work on this later if needed. We can not fix everything at once.
>   *[Source](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/pull/15903)*

Also, it seems like the actual problem is with the msbuild part within the mono formula.

I'm not that experienced with Linuxbrew but maybe you could try to [install mono separately](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin) and then install scriptcs with the `--ignore-dependencies` flag? It's possible that it won't work but it might be worth the try. I would also check whether msbuild is installed with mono and if not, install it with .NET Core.

Another option you have is to follow the official guideline on the scriptcs GitHub repository. They instruct you to install the Scriptcs Version Manager (SVM) and then use it to install the latest version of Scriptcs. By doing that, you can bypass the whole Linuxbrew stuff. You can find the instructions [here](https://github.com/scriptcs-contrib/svm/wiki/Installing-svm).